# Jquery control input field

Tags: jquery, digit

How can Jquery control input type="text" 4 digit, if user type 5 digit, the first one will remove to keep 4 digit ?

for example:
input > A001

if
input > A0015, change to 0015, the first digit will auto remove

Comment: Use `pattern` attribute with regex `[0-9]{4}` on `input`. Bind `key**` event on `input`, in handler check if length is greater than 4, remove first char, update value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `input` event to your `input text element` and check its length on each `input` and if its greater than 4 use `substring` to remove 1st character.

```
$('input').on('input',function(){
   var val=this.value;
     if(val.length>4)
        this.value=this.value.substring(1);
})
```

**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ys6t3h1y/)**

**Simpler version**

```
$('input').on('input',function(){
   this.value=this.value.length>4?this.value.substring(1):this.value;
})
```

**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ys6t3h1y/1/)**

Comment: if input is base on button, such as button 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/0.

Comment: @kenleung Could you please explain more about your comment?

Comment: if the input field is set readonly="true", using <button data-value="1"> 1 </button> to input the value, how to limit 5 digit ?

Comment: Could you create a html example?

Comment: `<input type="text" class="form-control input-table" name="username" id="username" readonly="true" />`
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom btn-sq sharp user" data-value="1">1</button>`
Jquery:
`$(".user").click(function(){
 $("#username").val( $("#username").val() + $(this).attr("data-value") );
});`

Comment: And how you are trying to add the values to input?

Comment: @kenleung **[`Something like this?`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ys6t3h1y/2/)**